# How to unencapsulate string for another string?

Tags: python, string, unicode

I'd like to unencapsulate a string (in Python) from another string.

For example, from:

```
>>> string1
"u'abcde'"
```

I'd like to get:

```
>>> string2
'abcde'
```

Comment: `string1.split("'")[1]` also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want the function `eval`

```
>>> stri = "u'abcde'"
>>> eval(stri)
'abcde'

>>> help(eval)
Help on built-in function eval in module builtins:

eval(...)
    eval(source[, globals[, locals]]) -> value

    Evaluate the source in the context of globals and locals.
    The source may be a string representing a Python expression
    or a code object as returned by compile().
    The globals must be a dictionary and locals can be any mapping,
    defaulting to the current globals and locals.
    If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.
```

As per the below comments, you need to use `ast.literal_eval` function instead of in-built eval function because eval will evaluate arbitrary (and potentially dangerous) code, whereas `ast.literal_eval` will only evaluate Python literals.

```
>>> import ast
>>> stri = "u'abcde'"
>>> ast.literal_eval(stri)
'abcde'
```

Comment: for safety you should use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval`

Comment: @jamylak may i know why?

Comment: Yeah, to elaborate, you could inject whatever code you want inside `eval` to delete all your files and other things.

Comment: @AvinashRaj because `eval` will evaluate arbitrary (and potentially dangerous) code, whereas `ast.literal_eval` will only evaluate Python literals. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/3001761.

Comment: Thanks `^.*\b(jon|jamy)`